# Unity new input system image drag and drop on mobile touch screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am configuring Survival Pro Controls by polymind games in which there is Unity's new input system. I am facing a problem of drag and drop in Inventory system in it. They use [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NItx.png) pass through and button in it. It is working in pc but on mobile touch, is is not working. I have lose 3 days in it. If somebody has configure mobile controls of Survival Pro by Polymind Games or have faced this problem, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to contact their chat support? or is it a pirated asset?

Comment: I am a new unity developer and i take it from my friend. I don't know about it whether it is a paid or pirated asset. I have also emailed polymind games 2 mins ago. Thanks for your suggestion